# How to add bundling and minification to an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I have just upgraded an ASP.NET MVC 3 project to MVC 4, and am now trying to add bundling and minification facilities to it. So far I have installed [Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework](http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.web.optimization) via NuGet and added System.Web.Optimization among the Razor namespaces in Web.config:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <pages>
    <namespaces>
      ...
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      ...
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
  ...
</system.web>
```

However, @Styles and @Scripts are still not directly accessible in my Razor views (*.cshtml), I am forced to prefix them with the System.Web.Optimization namespace. Any clues as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In which web.config did you add the namespace? There is one in the views folder and another in the root of project. You have to add the namespace in both.

Comment: Ah, that could well be it. I only added modified the root one. Will try your suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: Ok. Good look. Don't forget restart the Visual Studio if that don't work successfully

Comment: @vfabre why I must restart the Visual Studio after adding namespace to web.config?

Comment: @amirhosseinab I don't know why exactly, but sometimes they don't recognize the new namespaces.