# Telerik option not displaying in the intellisense after HTML in the .cshtml page

Tags: asp.net, telerik, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-grid, visual-studio-2012

I have added Telerik dlls in the project reference..also included telerik namespace in View's web.config

Then also, Telerik option not displaying in the intellisense after HTML in the .cshtml page. After typing HTML. "Telerik" option is not displaying in the intellisence.

Provide me a solution for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build entire solution and restart the Visual Studio,  I think that will solve your problem.

Regards

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936005/how-to-add-bundling-and-minification-to-an-asp-net-mvc-project/11937804#11937804) maybe you forgotten add namespace in some web.config. I hope this help